# How to calculate inverse of Variance Gamma call price formula using Newton-Raphson search

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, inverse, finance, newton-raphson

The Variance Gamma call price formula is given by:

$$C(0)= \int\gamma(R) e^{-rT} \int f\left(S(0) e^{\theta R+\omega T+\frac12 \sigma^2 R} e^{rT-\frac12 \sigma^2 R+\sqrt{T}\sqrt{R/T} \sigma W}\right)g(W)\,dW\,dR$$

How do I use Newton-Raphson search to obtain the inverse in terms of $\sigma$?

Notes:

- The inner integral is the  Black-Scholes price of an option with payoff $f$ with spot equal to $S(0) e^{\theta R+\omega T+\frac12 \sigma^2 R}$ and volatility $\sigma \sqrt{R/T}$. Black-Scholes can be substituted for the inner integral and then the outer integral can be computed numerically
- $\gamma(R)$ is the density of the Gamma distribution
- $g$ is the standard normal density
- $W$ is a random $N(0,1)$ draw
- $R$ is fixed random  time
- $r, \theta, \omega, T$ are parameters

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 2 of [The Variance Gamma Process and Option Pricing](http://www.math.nyu.edu/research/carrp/papers/pdf/VGEFRpub.pdf) gives a closed-form solution for the call price in terms of $\sigma$, the volatility associated with the underlying Wiener process.

Call this $C\left(\sigma\right)$. If you know $C\left(\sigma\right)=C_0$ for some constant $C_0$ (i.e. the real observed price), you can use a Newton's method in the usual way:

$$\sigma_{n+1}=\sigma_{n}-(C\left(\sigma_{n}\right)-C_0)/C^{\prime}\left(\sigma_{n}\right)$$

with an initial guess $\sigma_0$. Under reasonable conditions, the iteration converges, and the point to which it converges is the volatility you are looking for.

It sounds to me, however, that you should first familiarize yourself with [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Comment: If you go to (A11) in that first file, the 'modified bessel function of the second kind and the degenerate hypergeometric function of two variables by equation' is really difficult to compute. I don't know how to compute that.

Comment: Any ideas on the best way to proceed?

Comment: All of those functions are available in most numerical computing environments (e.g. MATLAB). See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselk.html

Comment: How about the degenerate hypergeometric function of two variables? Is there any way to implement this in Excel VBA since there is an integral in this formula?

Comment: I don't know anything about Excel VBA.